# JavaScript Code executes even after commenting

Tags: javascript

I am trying to develop a small CRUD project using ASP .Net MVC as part of my learning experience, I am trying to use jQuery and Ajax to get the data and display it.

I am new to JavaScript and ajax, not sure If I am commenting it the wrong way.

In the following bit of code, I have commented the

```
$('#btnUpdate').show();
$('#btnAdd').hide()
```

functions, but they are still getting executed on the page.

```
function getbyID(CusId) {
$('#CustomerName').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
$('#Age').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
$('#Address').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');

$.ajax({
    url: "/Customers/getbyID/" + CusId,
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        $('#Id').val(result.Id);
        $('#CustomerName').val(result.CustomerName);
        $('#Age').val(result.Age);
        $('#Address').val(result.Address);

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        //$('#btnUpdate').show();
        //$('#btnAdd').hide();
    },
    error: function (errormessage) {
        alert(errormessage.responseText);
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

I cleaned the solution and build it again but the code is still getting executed. Is there a different way of commenting the code.

Well The problem is solved now, I cleared the browser Cache and it has started working. As I am new, I was not aware of the execution style of javascript.

Comment: clean your browser cache and try again

Comment: You can inspect your browser, and look at the Sources tab and see if they are actually commented out, or are cached, as @Vineesh is suggesting.

Comment: Thank you @Vineesh, clearing the browser Cache has worked.